# No longer can access web server from outside local network

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp

I'm running XAMPP locally on a Windows machine. For months I've had no trouble with my setup, but all of the sudden yesterday, anyone outside of my local network became unable to access the site. Anyone trying to access a page from outside the network now gets a 504 Gateway Timeout error. I'm not a pro with Apache and am totally confused as to what is wrong and why it didn't happen until now. Here are the things I know (or am pretty sure) aren't causing the problem:

- Apache just not working (I can connect locally)
- A problem with DNS resolution (The site can't be accessed by IP either)
- A problem with firewalls (neither Windows or my router's are blocking connections)
- A problem with port forwarding (These settings worked before and I haven't changed them, I have to assume they should still be right)
- Apache needing restarted.
- Nothing helpful in the Apache error.log.

This local server is only temporary, but it may be a month or so before I can get set up on a more permanent one. I would really appreciate if someone could help me peg down what is causing this issue.

Edit:

The most recent change I've made to the server is changing the permissions on the /tmp/ folder. I was having trouble with users not having the ability to upload files to the server, so I removed the read-only flag on that folder. The issues arose about 18 hours after this.

Comment: You forgot to explain how users _outside_ of your local network access the server. How is that _outside_ defined? How is network access done across that border?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. By 'outside' I'm referring to any computer which doesn't share an IP with my own, and these users are just pulling up the page normally via the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Systems don't share IPs. Each system has a separate one. Usually one defiens a network by its network mask, so by a _range_ of IPs regarded as _internal_ and everything else as _external_. You are talking about some router somewhere. Could it be that you use that router to forward requests to your server? If so, how does that work? I mean you have a problem with network access to the system. Don't you think it is important to explain how packages are routed in that network? How does name resolution work?

Comment: I would have to assume you're right in that guess. The DNS name resolves to my router's public IP. I'm not aware of the IP of the system on which the site is hosted, and I haven't configured the server to make use of it. It didn't occur to me to make the distinction. Does that have anything to do with my issue?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow, this is strange. Now where is that server of yours? Is it in a private system at home, probably connected to the internet via DSL and you are using something like a dynamic dns server for name resolution? Or is it "hosted" as you now say? If so, what router? What network topology? I mean we cannot _guess_ that. You have to tell us.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm not withholding info out of laziness. I'm giving as much information as I have the skill level to come up with. It is on my own private home system. As I stated, I am using a DNS server which resolves to my network's public IP address.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51640/discussion-between-arkascha-and-nathan)

Comment: Ok, further investigation showed up that this is a routing problem most likely caused by the router blocking all ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some great help in the comments, I learned that my router was no longer forwarding the connection to the correct machine on my local network. I'm still not sure how this happened without my changing the port forwarding settings, but next time my site is inexplicably down I'll be double checking that the correct port is open first.